# asp:LinkButton Render differently after update jquery ui version

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have web forms application and I'm upgrading JQuery-UI version from 1.8.4 to 1.12.1.

I have LinkButton control which render differently after the upgrade which missing all my styling for buttons.

below is code for link button

`<asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" runat="server" CssClass="clb_button" icon="ui-icon-person" Text="Register" meta:resourcekey="Register" 
                OnClick="btnRegister_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:onRegisterButtonClick();" onmouseover="window.status='';return true;" />`

in previous version it render to

```
<a onclick="javascript:onRegisterButtonClick();" d="ctl00_cphContent_btnRegister" class="clb_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" icon="ui-icon-person" onmouseover="window.status='';return true;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$btnRegister','')" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

Register

After upgrade it render to

```
<a onclick="javascript:onRegisterButtonClick();" id="ctl00_cphContent_btnRegister" class="clb_button ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" icon="ui-icon-person" onmouseover="window.status='';return true;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$btnRegister','')" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-person"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Register</a>
```

I looked into the old JQuery-UI.js and found they are adding "ui-button-text" class which does not exist in the new version of JQuery-UI.

Please help!